# Начальная страница браузера

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. Нужен совет, ну или помощь. Есть в каждом браузере начальные страницы. Ну или страницы часто посещаемых сайтов. При добавлении туда уже например яндекс или гугла, выглядит вот так
[image]
просто, красиво.
Хотелось бы для своего сайта, сделать красивое оформление на начальной странице. Но если честно я даже не представляю пока как запрос в гугл подать)) Подскажите куда рыть или, если не лень, то может на примере на простом объясните.

Comment: Гуглить, наверное, так: `express panel preview`. Возможно, поможет https://habrahabr.ru/post/115705/, но настораживает, что давно написано.

Comment: @Qwertiy благодарю. Слушайте, а как благодарить за ответ. Ну там плюсик или рейтинг поднять?

Comment: Никак, @Qwertiy должен оформить свой коментарий как ответ

Comment: @Crantisz понял. Тогда всем СПАСИБО ))

Comment: @Crantisz, написал ответ.

Comment: Написал ответ, можешь поставить плюсик и принять нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Гуглить, наверное, так: `express panel preview`.
Хотя меня несколько настораживает, что результаты довольно старые.

В https://habrahabr.ru/post/115705 говорится

1. Можно просто добавить иконку размером не меньше чем 114*114:

   ```
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://path/to/200x200image.png">
   ```
2. Использовать медиа-запрос с [`view-mode`](https://www.w3.org/TR/view-mode/):

   ```
   @media screen and (view-mode: minimized) {
     /* some styling of preview */
   }
   ```
3. Ответить на http-запрос, содержащий заголовок

   ```
   X-Purpose: preview
   ```

   соответствующим содержимым.